# Tomcat: how to log request(ed) domain?

Tags: tomcat, logging

We have multiple domains pointing to our Tomcat web application which are all served by our default `Host`:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="..." unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="???" resolveHosts="false" />
  <Context path="" docBase="..." allowLinking="true" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

Which `Valve` pattern do I need to configure to see to which domain the request has been sent (i.e. which domain the user had entered into the web browser)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Valve ... pattern="... &quot;%{Host}i&quot; ..." ... />
```

will do the job.